# OTP generation in nodejs using speakeasy :set expiry time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, speakeasy

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy to generate OTP and i would like the expiry to 10 minutes.

Here is the code for generation

```
const generateOtp = function generateOtp() {
    let token = speakeasy.totp({
        secret:process.env.OTP_KEY,
        encoding: 'base32',
        digits:4,
        window:10
    });
    return token;
}
```

**Verify OTP**

```
const verifyOtp = function verifyOtp(token){
    let expiry =  speakeasy.totp.verify({
        secret:process.env.OTP_KEY,
        encoding: 'base32',
        token: token,
        window:10
    });
    console.log(expiry)
}
```

But I don't know how to set the expiry to 10 minutes??

Comment: How to know the field value of secret. where can I find the secret otp key.

Comment: You can use `// Generate a secret key.
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length: 20});` to generate the secret key

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation you can find out that the base `step` is 30 seconds, so if you want to have an expiration time of 10 minutes you need to set up the `step` to `60`. Then, using the `verifyDelta` method you should be able to check if the token expired.

```
const generateOtp = function generateOtp() {
    let token = speakeasy.totp({
        secret:process.env.OTP_KEY,
        encoding: 'base32',
        digits:4,
        step: 60,
        window:10
    });
    return token;
}

const verifyOtp = function verifyOtp(token){
    let expiry =  speakeasy.totp.verifyDelta({
        secret:process.env.OTP_KEY,
        encoding: 'base32',
        token: token,
        step: 60,
        window:10
    });
    console.log(expiry)
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but the  the token is expired very fast (ie with in two minutes)

Answer (score 0):

In order to expire the token after a while , you need to use the `step` option of `speakeasy` package like this :

```js
speakeasy.time({
    encoding: "base32",
    secret: "secret",
    digits: 4,
    step: 600, // expire after 10 minutes
});

speakeasy.time.verify({
    token: "1234",
    secret: "secret",
    encoding: "base32",
    digits: 4,
    step: 600, // expire after 10 minutes
});
```

Just make sure that the options you provide for generating token are the same as `verify`.